# how to read json and display in html

Tags: javascript, json, report

I'm placing some order and storing the order information in a JSON file (`order_details.json`). This is how data look like :

```
[{
    "uniqueID": "CHECKOUT_IE01",
    "orderID": "4001820182",
    "date": "06-02-2019 16:55:32.321",
    "cartTotal": "€19.98"
}, {
    "uniqueID": "CHECKOUT_DK01",
    "orderID": "6001825057",
    "date": "06-02-2019 16:56:15.976",
    "cartTotal": "318 DKK"
}]
```

Now i want to make a HTML report where i can fetch all these data and can display in html format.

No idea which technology i have to use. What i have tried so far is, created js code as below:

```
var fs = require(['fs']);
var data = fs.readFileSync("D:\\order-detail.json", "utf8");
var data1 = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data1);
var unique_id = data1[0].uniqueID;  
var order_id = data1[0].orderID;    
var order_date = data1[0].date; 
var cart_total = data1[0].cartTotal;

document.getElementById("uid").innerHTML = unique_id;
document.getElementById("oid").innerHTML = order_id;
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = order_date;
document.getElementById("ctotal").innerHTML = cart_total;
```

and HTML

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
<h3>Values from Json</h3>
<div>
<span id="uid"></span>
<span id="oid"></span>
<span id="date"></span>
<span id="ctotal"></span>
</div>
```

But its not working, I'm getting below error in console-

```
dashboard.html:8 Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function
    at myFunction (dashboard.html:8)
    at onload (dashboard.html:25)
myFunction @ dashboard.html:8
onload @ dashboard.html:25
require.js:5 GET file:///D:/JSON/fs.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
req.load @ require.js:5
load @ require.js:5
load @ require.js:5
fetch @ require.js:5
check @ require.js:5
enable @ require.js:5
enable @ require.js:5
(anonymous) @ require.js:5
(anonymous) @ require.js:5
each @ require.js:5
enable @ require.js:5
init @ require.js:5
(anonymous) @ require.js:5
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:5
o @ require.js:5
requirejs @ require.js:5
myFunction @ dashboard.html:7
onload @ dashboard.html:25
require.js:5 Uncaught Error: Script error for "fs"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:5)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:5)
```

i'm not sure whats wrong or the way i'm using is wrong. Any help would be great appreciated

Comment: Have you tried changing `var fs = require(['fs']);` to `var fs = require('fs');`?

Comment: Yes i did, that time i was getting `Uncaught Error: Module name "fs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`

Comment: Are you using `Node` or similar framework? because in plain browser JavaScript, `require` is not a function. And when using `Node` the proper syntax is `require('fs');`

Comment: You're mixing node.js with browser javascript. `require` is only available due to coincidence - it's being supplied by whatever module bundler you're using. Even if you could load `fs`, it wouldn't work. Look in to the fetch api to learn how to load data in the browser (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing `Node` with plain Browser JavaScript. Normal JavaScript does not have a definition for `require`, if it does it is because another library you are using has declared it will not do what you are expecting. The simplest way to load data from a browser is using an `XMLHttpRequest`, here is an example:

```js
loadURL("file:///D:/order-detail.json", onDataLoaded);

function onDataLoaded(data) {
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  var unique_id = data[0].uniqueID;
  var order_id = data[0].orderID;
  var order_date = data[0].date;
  var cart_total = data[0].cartTotal;

  document.getElementById("uid").innerHTML = unique_id;
  document.getElementById("oid").innerHTML = order_id;
  document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = order_date;
  document.getElementById("ctotal").innerHTML = cart_total;
}

function loadURL(url, callBack) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  xhr.onloadend = onLoadEnd(xhr, callBack);
  xhr.send();
}

function onLoadEnd(request, callBack) {
  return function() {
    var status = request.status;
    var result = String(request.response);
    if (status >= 200 && status < 300) callBack(result);
  };
}
```

Due to security reasons, some browsers (i.e. Chrome) might block the request. To resolve this, try adding the JSON file to your IIS (and then change `file://D:\\order-detail.json` to `localhost/addPathHere/order-detail.json`).
Here is a [simple tutorial](https://www.laserfiche.com/support/webhelp/workflow/9.0/en-us/content/resources/Configuration/Installation%20and%20Migration/Installing%20IIS%20Components%20Windows%207%20and%20Vista.htm) to activate your local IIS server (assuming you are using windows).

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: method is not defined` and location is `xhr.open(method, url, true);`

Comment: @NarendraR Sorry, change `method` to `"GET"`. I've edited the answer

Comment: Now `jquery.min.js:2 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///D:/JSON/order-detail.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes:`

Comment: 1. `jquery.min.js:2`? How did that appear? I didn't use any jQuery in my answer. 2. That behavior is expected when using chrome (as stated in the answer). Try firefox or adding the json to your IIS

Comment: issue is with chrome i can see the result in firefox

Comment: Are there any further questions and/or problems regarding the issue? If not, can you please accept an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

Replace **./JSON/order-detail.json** with your json file path.

```js
$.getJSON('./data.json', function(item) {
  item.forEach(function(data) {
    return [
      document.getElementById("uid").innerHTML += data.uniqueID + "</br>",
      document.getElementById("oid").innerHTML += data.orderID + "</br>",
      document.getElementById("date").innerHTML += data.date + "</br>",
      document.getElementById("ctotal").innerHTML += data.cartTotal + "</br>"
    ];
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Values from Json</h3>
<div>
  <span id="uid"></span>
  <span id="oid"></span>
  <span id="date"></span>
  <span id="ctotal"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Getting this `jquery.min.js:2 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///D:/JSON/order-detail.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes:`

Comment: @NarendraR try using a relative path i.e. `./JSON/order-detail.json`. let me know if that works.

Comment: issue is with chrome i can see the result in firefox

Comment: Yeah this is due to security, try using a localhost to run your project. See this answer for details `https://stackoverflow.com/a/10752078/7626277` hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `NodeJS` pattern in Client side javascript. In front-end You can import `JSON` file directly using `jQuery`.

```
$(function(){
        $.getJSON('order-detail.json',function(data){
            $.each(data,function(i,order){

             //your implementation here..
             // Can access data like order.uniqueID , order.orderID

            });
        }).error(function(){
            console.log('error');
        });
    });
```

> The **.json** file should be accessible under your domain like `CSS,JS,Image resources`. You **can't** access with full path like `C:\yourpath\file.json`